# Enable disable a security policy in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have created a Security Policy to implement Row Level Security (RLS) in SQL Server 2016. There is some specific time in a month when the security policy will be applicable. I am planning to write a job which will enable or disable the Security Policy, but I am not getting the SQL command to disable or enable it.

I know that I need to set the check_policy to OFF

```
CHECK_POLICY = { OFF }
```

Visually I am able to do it using Sql Server Management Studio by right clicking on the Security Policy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Won't this work..

```
ALTER SECURITY POLICY <<your security policy>>
WITH (STATE = OFF);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [TheGameiswar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39065632/6783526) works I wanted to add that if you get an error saying

> Cannot find the object "[security filter name]" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Append `[security]` before the filter name

For example if your filter name is "ProfilesFilter"

```
ALTER SECURITY POLICY [security][ProfilesFilter] WITH (STATE=OFF)
```

This is probably a given for some but I am less fluent with SQL/SQL Server